# Packer not installing Hop.nvim

Tags: neovim, packer

I am trying to install `hop.nvim` using packer.  I have about 35 other plugins installed without any issues. For some reason, I can't install `hop.nvim`.

The other plugins install fine if I use `:PackerSync`.

For some reason, it passes `hop.nvim` and I don't get any error messages.

This is what I got in my init.lua.

```lua
return require('packer').startup(function(use)
-- Packer can manage itself
use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
-- If you are using Packer
use 'shaunsingh/nord.nvim'
-- ... other plugins
use {'phaazon/hop.nvim'} 
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```lua
  use 'phaazon/hop.nvim'
```

Without the braces.

Or as [documented](https://github.com/phaazon/hop.nvim#using-packer) in hop:

```lua
use {
  'phaazon/hop.nvim',
  branch = 'v2', -- optional but strongly recommended
  config = function()
    -- you can configure Hop the way you like here; see :h hop-config
    require'hop'.setup { keys = 'etovxqpdygfblzhckisuran' }
  end
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways.  No joy....

Comment: And if you keep only hop to verify that the problem is not in one of the previous lines (maybe you could give us the full call I stead of the excerpt)?

Comment: my mistake.  The first line worked.  i had to put the setup on a separate lua file.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback!